# Как удалить динамически созданный элемент?

Tags: javascript

Помогите разобраться.   https://jsfiddle.net/6npssxa9/
Нужно при клике на крестик(.close) удалить соответствующий li

```
//Функция при нажатии ""записать""
function write() {
  var newLi = document.createElement('li');
  newLi.innerHTML = document.getElementById("inp").value;
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("inp").value;
  var iv = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("Введите Дело !");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("quest").appendChild(newLi);
  }
  document.getElementById("inp").value = "";
  document.getElementById('del').style.display = 'block';
  newLi.className = 'draggable';

  //Создание крестика для удаления одного дела 
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  newLi.appendChild(span);
  return;
}

//обработчик клик удаления одного дела    
var close = document.getElementById("quest");
closes = function() {
  this.target.parentNode.removeChild(li);
}
close.addEventListener('click', closes)




//Функция при нажатии ""Удалить Все""
function del() {
  document.getElementById("quest").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('del').style.display = 'none';
  return;
}

//События при нажатии на кнопки
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', write);
document.getElementById('del').addEventListener('click', del);
```

Comment: есть какие объективные причины не использовать jquery к примеру? зы: оработчика ваш навешивается при старте, когда добавленных элементов еще нет (к одному элементу). к вновь созданным элементам он отношения не имеет.

Comment: @teran, проблема ещё и в том, что обработка навешивается не на кнопку удаления, а на весь список

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Устанавливайте обработчик правильному элементу и делайте это при его создании:

```
//Функция при нажатии ""записать""
function write() {
  var newLi = document.createElement('li');
  newLi.innerHTML = document.getElementById("inp").value;
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("inp").value;
  var iv = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("Введите Дело !");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("quest").appendChild(newLi);
  }
  document.getElementById("inp").value = "";
  document.getElementById('del').style.display = 'block';
  newLi.className = 'draggable';

  //Создание крестика для удаления одного дела 
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.addEventListener('click', closes)
  span.appendChild(txt);
  newLi.appendChild(span);
  return;
}

//обработчик клик удаления одного дела
closes = function() {
  this.parentNode.remove();
}

//Функция при нажатии ""Удалить Все""
function del() {
  document.getElementById("quest").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('del').style.display = 'none';
  return;
}

//События при нажатии на кнопки
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', write);
document.getElementById('del').addEventListener('click', del);
```